# when use rstudio make r package, the package cant output chinese words,why?

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I try to use rstudio to make r package. but the package cant print the right words.

below is the code in package:

```
hello3 <- function(){
  print("测试")
}
```

but when use the package ,the output is :

```
> library(hr)
> hello3()
[1] "娴嬭瘯"
```

**It's evident that the output text into other encodings.**

**What reason is this?**

***How to solve this problem?***

Comment: You might need to specify the encoding the `DESCRIPTION` file, e.g. with an entry like `Encoding: UTF-8` (assuming your R source files are truly UTF-8 encoded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.just add this code into description:

```
Encoding:UTF-8
```

then,when use the package , can output correct chinese words.

Answer (score 0):

Using multi-byte characters in your source code makes a lot of headache.
I would use unicode expression as below.

```
hello3 <- function() 
{
  print("\u6d4b\u8bd5")
}
```

Then,

```
hello3()
[1] "测试"
```

If you do not know what is the right expression for your words, try:

```
sprintf("%x", utf8ToInt("测试"))
[1] "6d4b" "8bd5"
```

Comment: thanks. I solved the problem.just add this code into description: Encoding:UTF-8